# how to pass values to constructor?

Tags: c#, oop

**I am sorry for my question is a little theoretical**

I am new to OOP and studying the following code.

```
public interface IShape
{
    double getArea();
}

public class Rectangle : IShape
{
    int lenght;
    int width;        

    public double getArea()
    {
        return lenght * width;
    }       
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    int radius;       

    public double getArea()
    {
        return (radius * radius) * (22 / 7);
    }        
}

public class SwimmingPool
{
    IShape innerShape;
    IShape outerShape;

    SwimmingPool(IShape _innerShape, IShape _outerShape)
    {
        //assignment statements and validation that poolShape can fit in borderShape;
    }

    public double GetRequiredArea()
    {
        return outerShape.getArea() - innerShape.getArea();
    }

}
```

This code calculate area of different shapes. I can see constructor of SwimingPool class but I am not getting how to pass values to constructor. I have not done programming using Interfaces before. Please guide me 3 things:

1. How to pass values on design time.
2. How to pass values on run time (when both parameters can be of any type).
3. How to do validations here in OO way ?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are using interfaces so in your `SwimmingPool` class, the constructor will require two `IShape` parameters.  Since you need an implementation in order to use your interface, such as your `Rectangle` and `Circle`, you would simply do something like this:

```
class Pool
{
    private IShape _InnerShape;
    private IShape _OuterShape;

    public Pool(IShape inner, IShape outer)
    {
        _InnerShape = inner;
        _OuterShape = outer;
    }

    public double GetRequiredArea()
    {
        return _InnerShape.GetArea() - _OuterShape.GetArea();
    }

  }
```

and the usage would be something like

```
IShape shape1 = new Rectangle() { Height = 1, Width = 3 };
IShape shape2 = new Circle() { Radius = 2 };

Pool swimmingPool = new Pool(shape1, shape2); 
Console.WriteLine(swimmingPool.GetRequiredArea());
```

It seems, based on your comment, is that you want to test if an object implements an interface.

You can do something like this

```
if (shape1 is Circle) //...
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan Crosby, it is ok on design time. Kindly advice how to handle it on run time when we are not sure about types ? I do not exectly understand it but may be in Polymorphism ? Thanks

Comment: @haansi: The types will be anything that implement `IShape` since we defined a constructor that takes two `IShape` objects.  You don't need to know the types at run-time necessarily.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Crosby, if I will not know the type how I will instantiate ? like you did:

IShape shape1 = new Rectangle() { Height = 1, Width = 3 };
IShape shape2 = new Circle() { Radius = 2 };

Here it is known one type is Rectangle and other is Circle.

Please advice.

Comment: What my mean is shape1, shape2 both can be circle or rectangle combination of them.

Comment: @haansi: You can't instantiate an interface, you will have to provide an implemented type, such as in my example above.  You are simply passing in any object that implements `IShape`.  Could be a cylinder, triangle, circle, square, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like this

```
SwimmingPool(IShape innerShape, IShape outerShape)
{
    this.innerShape = innerShape;
    this.outerShape = outerShape;

    this.Validate();
}

private void Validate()
{
     // or some other condition
     if ( GetRequiredArea() < 0 ){
          throw new Exception("The outer shape must be greater than the inner one");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @scibuff, I need your advice on how to pass values to constructor while making object of SwimmingPool class ? Confusion is innerShape and outerShape can be in any shape (circule or rectangular) How to know which one to pass on run time ?

Comment: that validation won't be sufficient - you can have a circle that will not fit into a rectangle, even with the rectangle having a larger area

Comment: @haansi, yes that's the point, you don't care what kind of object it is as long as it implements the `GetArea` method. So, example, you can do something like this: `Cicle c1 = new Circle( 10 ); Circle c2 = new Circle( 20 ); SwimmingPool sp = new SwimmingPool( c1, c2 );`

Comment: @BrokenGlass, yes of course, I was demonstrating how to do things in general, not how to implement proper validation

Comment: Thanks scibuff, please guide how to pass values to constructo on run time when we are not sure about types ? I dont understand it correctly but may be Polymorphism ? please guide